# Is it possible to use spacy without having administrator access?

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, spacy

I am trying to use spacyr on a computer where I cannot have admin access, that is just the reality of it. I have found that I can download and install spacy and the en model using anaconda into my conda environment (spacy_condaenv), but I cannot create a link due to a lack of admin access. Here is the full error:

Error: Couldn't link model to 'en'
    Creating a symlink in spacy/data failed. Make sure you have the required
    permissions and try re-running the command as admin, or use a
    virtualenv. You can still import the model as a module and call its
    load() method, or create the symlink manually.

```
D:\Anaconda\envs\spacy_condaenv\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm -->
D:\Anaconda\envs\spacy_condaenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en


Creating a shortcut link for 'en' didn't work (maybe you don't have
admin permissions?), but you can still load the model via its full
package name: nlp = spacy.load('{name}')
Download successful but linking failed
```

I primarily work in R and am VERY new to python, therefore I am struggling to find a workaround. Is there anyway this can be done??? Is there a way I can move the necessary libraries to a folder that does not require admin access?

## This is the basic code to get spacy up and running in r:

install.packages(spacyr)

library(spacyr)

spacy_install()
spacy_initialize(condaenv = "spacy_condaenv", model = "en")

spacy_download_langmodel("en") #<- this function created the above error.

Comment: Does setting `model = "en_core_web_sm"` work? Basically, the error message means that spaCy couldn't set up a symbolic link to allow you to load the model `en_core_web_sm` by the shortcut `"en"`. But since the model *did* install correctly and is in your site packages, spaCy should still be able to load it via its full name.

Comment: Well, I tried that now I'm getting a new message in R Studio: Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ValueError: spacy.vocab.Vocab has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 96, got 104

Comment: I think I fixed the last issue and again I have reinstalled the en model using spacy_download_langmodel() with model = "en_core_web_sm" but I still get that same error. when i try to move forward with my analysis in R. Its not clear to me in the documentation, but is linking necessary to use spacy in R?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be – at least not from spaCy's perspective. That `ValueError` message sound more like there's something wrong with your spaCy installation and you might have ended up with a mismatched environment. So you might want to try reinstalling `spacyr` from scratch with a fresh conda environment.